# Query about List Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, list-comprehension

I have a list,

```
test = ['Travel Industry XML Implementation Guide Aviation Information Data Exchange (AIDX)', 'International Air Transport Association (IATA)', 'America (A4A)', 'Airports Council International (ACI)', 'International Air Transport Association (IATA)', 'America (A4A)', 'Airports Council International (ACI)', 'COLLABORATIVE DECISION MAKING (CDM)', 'HANDLING OF GENERAL AVIATION (GA)', 'Xchange (AIDX)']
```

So, I'm calculating the number of Upper Case Characters per element in the list and the length of each element in the list like this,

```
upr_case_count, Length = [], []
for element in test:
    upr_case_count.append(len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', element)))
    Length.append(len(element) - sum(element.count(x) for x in '() '))
```

Which Returns,

```
upr_case_count = [15, 8, 3, 6, 8, 3, 6, 30, 27, 5]
 Length = [71, 40, 10, 31, 40, 10, 31, 30, 27, 11]
```

But, when I try using List Comphrehension I get

```
[len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', element)) for i in test]
```

I get,

```
[5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

Also, how to write the String Length Calculation in a List Comprehension ?

What am i doing wrong here ?

I am new to Python.

Comment: `element != i`, I'm afraid

Comment: I'm trying to run this outside all loops

Answer (score 0):

It works. What is `element` in your comprehension? I replaced with `i` because that is the item returned from the for loop for test.

```py
import re

test = ['Travel Industry XML Implementation Guide Aviation Information Data Exchange (AIDX)', 'International Air Transport Association (IATA)', 'America (A4A)', 'Airports Council International (ACI)', 'International Air Transport Association (IATA)', 'America (A4A)', 'Airports Council International (ACI)', 'COLLABORATIVE DECISION MAKING (CDM)', 'HANDLING OF GENERAL AVIATION (GA)', 'Xchange (AIDX)']

[len(re.findall(r'[A-Z]', i)) for i in test]
```

Output:

```
[15, 8, 3, 6, 8, 3, 6, 30, 27, 5]
```

Comment: Omg, I never noticed that. The element was the problem. Thank You. The Element is part of another list.

Answer (score 0):

Using nested comprehensions instead of a regex it'd be:

```
[len([c for c in s if c.isupper()]) for s in test]
```

Comment: @Jab in python3? `---> 12 [len(c for c in s if c.isupper()) for s in test]

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`